# What are the 2003 Wendy's Promotional Pokémon Toys?

Tags: pokemon, merchandise

On Bulbapedia, there is an article about [2003 Wendy's promotional *Pokémon* toys](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/2003_Wendy%27s_promotional_Pok%C3%A9mon_toys). It currently says:

> The 2003 Wendy's promotional Pokémon toys were a set of five toys distributed with Kids Meals at Wendy's in May of 2003. Each toy also came with one of fifteen cards.

It also links to a missing video by a user (TheMasterGamerify) who is no longer on YouTube.

How long did this campaign run? What were these toys, and what were the fifteen cards available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This link](http://www.pokemonelite2000.com/pastnews0503.html) seems to document all the toys and cards. There were 5 toys. These were a Pikachu keychain, Pikachu Clock, Charizard Treasure Box, Kecleon Keychain, and a Celebi compass (though the image has Torchic). Here's images of all five:

[image: Pika]
[image: Other Pika]
[image: Red winged lizard box]
[image: Chameleon keychain]
[image: The coolest toy]

According to [this site](http://pkmn.net/?action=news&page=viewnews&id=252), the promotion began May 19th 2003, and very likely lasted 5 weeks. I haven't been able to find a more definitive confirmation of that.

Here's the promotional image used at the time to advertise the event (from the same link with the dates):

[image: yay Wendy's]

As for why the compass is called a Celebi compass, it really did have a Celebi design. The back of the case had a Celebi on it:

[image: Proof it's a Celebi!]

(image taken from [this Ebay auction](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2002-POKEMON-LUGIA-TOY-5-OF-15-WENDYS-KIDS-MEAL-/121078921340?nma=true&si=8QDzPI3iSUu0v0ySFKPMsrC9M9g%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557). Thanks to Krazer for finding it.)

It seems that you could put the Lugia, Torchic, and Kecleon trading cards from the promotion into it, and perhaps others. The above image has the back of the Lugia card. Here's a different version with the front of the Lugia card.

[image: now lets zoom out!].

(taken from [this Lugia collection](http://slothyshroom.weebly.com/lugia-collection.html))

The Pikachu clock could hold a card as well, though I don't think it really did anything with it the same way the compass worked with those cards, and the cards fit inside the Charizard box.

[This site](http://myuutsuudestiny150.tripod.com/wendys.html) lists all the cards, with images for the front and back. They are:

- 1 Pikachu

[image: Pika Pika]
[image: Pikachu!]

- 2 Charizard

[image: Char!]
[image: Chaaaaaarizard!]

- 3 Mewtwo

[image: He know what you're thinking!]
[image: Because he's psychic]

- 4 Tyranitar

[image: Tyrani!]
[image: Tyranitaaaaar!]

- 5 Lugia

[image: Lugia is Psychic, too]
[image: Lugia also know what you are thinking!]

- 6 Feraligatr

[image: Ferali]
[image: -gatr!]

- 7 Gyarados

[image: Gyara-gyara]
[image: Doooos!]

- 8 Kyogre

[image: Not all legendaries can speak]
[image: I wonder why....]

- 9 Latios & Latias

[image: Hey look!]
[image: Twins!]

- 10 Torchic

[image: Man this little one evolves]
[image: it's so OP!]

- 11 Groudon

[image: This legendary can't speak either]
[image]

- 12 Mudkip

[image: So I heard...]
[image: that you like Mudkips]

- 13 Duskull

[image: It's sure dark...]
[image: ...at dusk]

- 14 Treecko

[image: Who's that Pokemon?!]
[image: It's Treecko!]

- 15 Kecleon

[image: Kek-kek-kek]
[image: Kecleon!]